# lambda function fails with KeyError tags

Tags: python, lambda

I have a Lambda Python 3.8 function that has run successfully every night for a few years now but starting about 5 days ago it's failing. We have not made any changes to the code.

The error we see in the CloudWatch logs is:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'Tags'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
    for tag in instance['Tags']:
```

Below is the function, I've replaced the account numbers with dummy info for this post.

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    region='us-east-1'
    
    aws_account_numbers = ["111111111111","222222222222"]
        
    for account in aws_account_numbers:
        instance_list = []

        print(("working on account : %s" % (account)))
        roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::%s:role/CrossAccount-Terminationprotection-Role" % account
        stsClient = boto3.client('sts')
        sts_response = stsClient.assume_role(RoleArn=roleArn,RoleSessionName='AssumeCrossAccountRole', DurationSeconds=1800)
              
        ec2client = boto3.client(service_name='ec2', region_name=region,
            aws_access_key_id = sts_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            aws_secret_access_key = sts_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
            aws_session_token = sts_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
        response = ec2client.describe_instances()
        for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
            for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
                skip = 0
                for tag in instance['Tags']:
                   if ((tag['Key'] == 'CloudEndure_Replication_Service') and
                       (tag['Value'].lower() == 'true')):
                      print(('Skipping Cloud Endure Instance ID: %s'% (instance["InstanceId"])))
                      skip = 1
                if (skip == 0):
                   instance_list.append(instance["InstanceId"])
        
        for instance in instance_list:
            print(('working on instance id: %s'% (instance)))
            response  = ec2client.modify_instance_attribute(
                DisableApiTermination={
                    'Value': True
                },
                InstanceId=instance
            )
            
            print(('Deltetion protection is on for %s' % (instance)))
    return 'Success'
```

Comment: What can be do about it ? `instance` object as no key `Tags` that's it

Comment: Was there perhaps some kind of odd/null reservation or odd/null instance which did not have a `'Tags'` key

Comment: Use: `for tag in instance.get('Tags', []):` Do similarly for other response keys if you can't guarantee that the key will be present (or pre-test if the key is in the dict). The boto3 docs are not the best here, and they don't indicate if Tags will be an empty list or simply absent if there are no tags.

Comment: Thanks jarmod, that did the trick, I changed ```for tag in instance['Tags']:``` to ```for tag in instance.get('Tags', []):``` and it now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you write the code as follows:

```
for tag in instance.get('Tags', []):
    # do something with tag
```

What this will do is iterate over the tags, if present, and iterate over an empty list, if not. The `dict.get` method is a very useful way to indicate the default value that you'd like returned if the request key is not present in the dict. And this code indicates a default value of `[]` (empty list) rather than, for example `None` because ordinarily you're expecting a list and the empty list is iterable, so you can use it in a for loop.

Do similarly for other response keys if you can't guarantee that the key will be present (or pre-test if the key is in the dict).

The boto3 docs don't clearly indicate if `Tags` will be an empty list or simply absent if there are no tags. This seems to be an omission in the docs.